# What do you call the frozen air that comes out of your mouth?

Tags: word-request

What do you call this water vapour coming out of your mouth during winter times?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We call it just **breath**. From Google Books:

> In the summer, it's stifling hot; in the winter, **you can see your breath**.
>
> But the upstairs in our house, where I slept, was unheated; in winter **you could see your breath** up there.
>
> See," I said, “ on this sunny side of the barn, where the air ,is warm, you **can't see your breath**; on the shady side it comes out like a cloud.

From the "[Handy Weather Answer Book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=XCb0W8fAzY8C&lpg=PA114&dq=in%20the%20winter%20you%20can%20see%20your%20breath&hl=ru&pg=PA114#v=onepage&q&f=false)":

> [image]

You can call it **water vapor** but common people talk about it as just **breath**.

Comment: And some people's breath is icy or hot when they breathe down your neck. [joke]